# How to connect Mini LVDS to standard LVDS or HDMI?

Tags: hdmi, lvds

I've purchased a LCD TFT Display (LG Display LA123WF-SL01) that has an absurd connecter that i haven't seen anywhere online that it has been used before. The name of the connector is FH28D-64S-0.5SH.

From the connector name i can see that the FH28D is the connector name variant and 64S is that it has 64 pins and 0.5SH is most likely the 0.5mm size.

Now onto the Mini LVDS stuff:

How can i convert this to HDMI? I have been googling around for a Mini LVDS 64 pin to HDMI but nothing actually comes up about Mini LVDS at all.

Can we rewire 64 pin Mini LVDS to LVDS -> HDMI?

The LG Display has a product specification PDF and i have found a complete pinout for the Mini LVDS.

Here: [image: lg display]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Pja.jpg): [image: lg display 2]

Comment: What’s “mini LVDS”? LVDS is not standardised, there are nearly as many connector sizes and layouts as there are screens, not to mention voltages, number of channels and more. What input/output are you looking for? HDMI in/LVDS out? Be advised it’s nearly necessarily going to be a custom board.

Comment: @jcaron yes, so HDMI into my Raspberry pi and LVDS into the Display. I have updated the original post with another picture where LG actually says "Mini-LVDS". Could you please elaborate on what custom board it will be?

Comment: If you search for HDMI to LVDS converter or controller you’ll find plenty of boards, but they are often very specific to certain LCD references. If you are very lucky you may be able to find a board which is directly compatible (Google seems to say no), if you are a bit less lucky you will have all the right signals etc but just the wrong wiring/connector (which may be a challenge by itself), and if you are even less lucky you’ll need to design your own board, but that’s most certainly not worth it for a single screen.

Comment: Why did you make a purchase of something that has an absurd connector?

Comment: @Andyaka Because this is the only screen in the open market that has cutted corners and is available to purchase to customers world wide other than Bosch. Even on how absurd the connector is, its worth it.

Comment: When submitting questions it helps all those trying to answer if you include links to the data sheets for the components you are asking about.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did you ever figure this out? I'm looking at getting this same display for a project I'm working on, but want to make sure I'll be able to get this working first.